# SQL Select record within time interval

Tags: sql

I have a table with a bunch of records:

```
userID    testID    value    time
1         1001      2        2009-09-05 06:25:00
1         1001      4        2009-09-05 07:25:00
1         1001      2        2009-09-05 03:25:00
1         1002      5        2009-09-05 06:25:00
1         1002      6        2009-09-05 07:25:00
1         1002      4        2009-09-05 03:25:00
```

The user enters at time x. I want to query the most recent value for each test within the first X hours of entrance. IE if he enters at 3:25 and I want the most recent value within 3 hours, I want to return

```
1         1001      2        2009-09-05 07:25:00
1         1002      5        2009-09-05 07:25:00
```

I'm not sure the best way to go about this, but here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT testID, value from table WHERE userID = 1 and 
    time <= timestamp 'enter_time' + INTERVAL '3 HOURS' as u INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT testID, max(time) as time from table WHERE time <= timestamp 
    'enter_time' + INTERVAL '3 HOURS' GROUP BY testID) as q 
    on u.itemid = q.itemid AND u.time = q.time
```

I'm getting a syntax error for this, but the code seems to be right. Could someone help me out a bit?

Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting, and what RBDMS is this for?  MySql? Oracle?

Comment: I'm on postgresql. The error is just "Syntax error on or near AS", where the AS is the AS u part.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the first query in parens.

```
(SELECT testID, value from table WHERE userID = 1 and 
    time <= timestamp 'enter_time' + INTERVAL '3 HOURS') as u INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT testID, max(time) as time from table WHERE time <= timestamp 
    'enter_time' + INTERVAL '3 HOURS' GROUP BY testID) as q 
    on u.itemid = q.itemid AND u.time = q.time
```